# INJECT_EVENTS permission not granted to privileged app

Tags: android, android-permissions

My app needs the `INJECT_EVENTS` permission to inject key events in other apps:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS" />
```

It is installed as a privilged app, in the `system/priv-app` folder of a rooted device, but it still doesn't have this permission.

Why? How can I get this permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least in current versions of Android, `INJECT_EVENTS` is a `signature`-level permission:

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

(from [the current `master` branch of the framework manifest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml))

Your app would need to be signed by the signing key that signed the firmware. Mostly, this is for device manufacturers or custom ROM developers.